# Efficiency query - how to get JUST page title (using PHP or JS)

Tags: javascript, php

Using google.com as an example, the HTML source for the page is quite large. About 390 lines.

All I want is, given some URL, to get the page title...

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-AU"><head><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><link href="/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" rel="shortcut icon"><meta content="origin" id="mref" name="referrer"><title>Google</title> ...
```

Which in that case is `Google`.

In PHP (or Javascript) is there a simple way for me to parse the page source, but stop as soon as I've ascertained the page title? I don't want to waste time and bandwidth downloading the rest of the page when all I need is the title.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `CURLOPT_RANGE` option to cURL to specify a byte range of the page to download.

Comment: But for any given URL I wouldn't know how many bytes to count in, all I know is to stop once the `</title>` tag closes.

Comment: You can do it in a loop, first requesting bytes 0-999, then 1000-1999, etc. until you get what you're looking for.

Comment: @KevinKloet You would have to download the entire page first before you can run that, and he's trying to avoid downloading the whole thing.

Comment: @KevinKloet How would he run Javascript at a third party site like google.com?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code is shown below:

> var title = document.getElementByTagName("title");